# Meaning of "I know for a fact don’t anybody go by there"

Tags: meaning

> I know for a fact *don’t anybody go by there.*

What is the meaning of the italicised part?

Comment: It's a local dialect with some strange syntax. It means the same as _I know for a fact that nobody goes by here._

Comment: @JohnLawler, a minor quibble: your *here* should be *there*.

Comment: I agree with JohnLawler's comment regarding dialect, except I'd say it means _I know for a fact 'Nobody should go there'_ or possibly _via there_. It would probably help if you mention where you've read/heard the sentence.

Comment: @Frank: I'm more familiar with *...don't **nobody** go [by] there*, but I don't think either that version or OP's would normally include any particular element of *should, ought to*. It's just a straightforward statement of fact - people *don't* go there, regardless of whether they should or shouldn't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For me it's hard to tell, if it's Dorset or something like that then I can imagine _don't anybody go_ to mean _nobody should_, but to make a proper 'guess', we'd need to know what dialect it is. Odds are it's American and means what JL says, but if it's English, it could be different

Comment: Found it - http://philarcher.org/books/tokillamockingbird/ - American. To Kill a Mockingbird - Harper Lee - Ch4... "I don't know what we could do, Scout. Who'd we give 'em back to? I know for a fact don't anybody go by there. Cecil goes by the back street an' all the way around by town to get home." (So much for the West Country accent!)

Comment: @Frank: I think you're mixing up *I know for a fact [some statement of fact]* with the imperative form *Don't anybody/any of **you** go there*. I suppose in principle an AAV speaker might say *"I know for sure don't nobody move"* (to mean *"I have definitely understood that nobody should move"*), but it would need to be a pretty contrived context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I'd got some weird West Country accent in my head, giving a dire warning, sort of Hammer House of Horror style. I should have looked for the quote first - attribution would've helped.

Answer (score 1):

By my experience and research, this seems to be AAVE and carries the meaning "I know for a fact that nobody passes by that" or "I know for a fact that nobody goes there". "Don't anybody" means "nobody" in standard English. "Go by there" could mean that nobody passes through/by a certain place *or* that nobody visits that place (stop by, one might say). Hope this helps. For basic clarification on AAVE syntax and grammar, I recommend Hawaii.edu's site: http://www.hawaii.edu/satocenter/langnet/definitions/aave.html. Hope this helps. Note that some of the vocabulary section may seem bizarre (unless you hail from Hawai'i) but the grammar is still useful.

Comment: That's a very useful link, Oedipus. Thanks for posting it!  And welcome to ELU!